# Why hover transform styles are getting removed after applying new transform styles with JavaSctript?

Tags: javascript, css

So I was playing around with Javascript and found a strange situation, I don't know if this is a bug or this is intended. After calling a function which changes the elements transform, changes also the elements hover style which includes the transform property as well.

[image: Here the transform: property and value is disabled]

Here is the code:

```js
let card_arr = [];
[...document.getElementsByTagName("article")].forEach(card => {
  let id = card.id;
  card_arr.push(id);
});
let index = 0;

function switchCards() {
  temp_arr = [];
  let selected_card_id = card_arr[index];
  card_arr.forEach(card_id => {
    let card = document.getElementById(card_id);
    if (card_id != selected_card_id) {
      card.style.transform = "translateY(0px)";
    } else {
      card.style.transform = "translateY(-120px)";
    }
  });

  if (index == card_arr.length) {
    index = 0;
  } else {
    index++;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  overflow: hidden;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

article {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 2em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}

article:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

#pink {
  background-color: rgb(255, 187, 246);
  border-color: rgb(255, 152, 241);
  color: rgb(255, 0, 221);
}

#green {
  background-color: rgb(171, 255, 154);
  border-color: rgb(128, 255, 103);
  color: rgb(43, 255, 0);
}

#cyan {
  background-color: rgb(154, 229, 251);
  border-color: rgb(104, 220, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 195, 255);
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <button onClick="switchCards()">Switch</button>
  <!--- After pressing this button the hover styles are removed --->
  <main>
    <article id="pink">1</article>
    <article id="green">2</article>
    <article id="cyan">3</article>
  </main>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I know I could probably fix it in Javascript by reasigning the style again somehow, but I didn't really expect a usual style to overwrite the hover style. Is there some simple solution for this?

Comment: It's not getting removed.  It's being overridden.  That's what the line means.  If it was removed, it wouldn't be there at all.  It looks like you are setting inline styles dynamically.  Inline styles are about as granular of a css rule that you can make.  And in general, the most granular css rule wins.

Comment: Inline styles (`card.style=...`) are the most specific type of styles you can apply. They override all other styles that include the same properties. You can learn about and practice with specificity [here](https://specificity.keegan.st/). CSS overriding (through specificity) is the basis for using CSS properly and leveraging its power.

Comment: But how do I not do inline styles and don't overwrite the hover style? @ScottMarcus

Comment: Apply or remove CSS classes with `element.classList.add()` and `element.classList.remove()`. You can read about `classList` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: You would either need to make classes for the other two states and swap those classes in and out, with them being less specific than the :hover rule, or alternatively you could change your hover rule to be `transform: scale(1.1) !important;`

Comment: But know that using `!important` is discouraged.

Comment: ^ agreed.  I try to not use it as much as possible, but I'll admit to using it in some cases.